# Compare two columns of dictionary in a data frame and add the key-value pair which does not exist in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which has two columns "gw_mac_rssi" & "edge_gw_mac_rssi". How to compare and add the key-value pair in "gw_mac_rssi" which doesnt exist?

```
df1:
mac             building    gw_mac_rssi                              edge_gw_mac_rssi
0010403bf0db    main        {'d827fc36gc0c':-45,'b827eb36fb0b':-67}  {'b827eb36fb0b':-82,'d827fc36gc0c':-82, 'c36gc0cd827f':-82}
bf0db0010403    south_tower {'ac233fc01111':-71,'ac233fc1113':-59}   {'ac233fc01111': -82, 'ac233fc01112': -82, 'ac233fc1113': -82}
```

How to check the keys are in same order as like "edge_gw_mac_rssi" column and If a key is missing how to replace the same key-value pair from "edge_gw_mac_rssi" to "gw_mac_rssi" column in the same order based on the group "mac" and "building" columns? The resultant data frame should be,

```
df2:
mac             building    gw_mac_rssi                                                    edge_gw_mac_rssi                              
0010403bf0db    main        {'b827eb36fb0b':-67, 'd827fc36gc0c':-45, 'c36gc0cd827f':-82}   {'b827eb36fb0b':-82,'d827fc36gc0c':-82, 'c36gc0cd827f':-82}
bf0db0010403    south_tower {'ac233fc01111':-71,'ac233fc01112': -82, 'ac233fc1113':-59}    {'ac233fc01111': -82, 'ac233fc01112': -82, 'ac233fc1113': -82}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
df['gw_mac_rssi'] = [{**y, **x} for x , y in zip(df['gw_mac_rssi'], df['edge_gw_mac_rssi'])]
```